# Duplicate entry 'nn' for key '.... '

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting this error quite alot, and my hibernate is acting strange when I try to insert objects into my tables in my mySQL database.

```
okt. 06, 2015 9:57:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
okt. 06, 2015 9:57:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Duplicate entry '77' for key 'UK_2gy9x2d1hqmk0d77o8ux44c6o'
okt. 06, 2015 9:57:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

When I look in MySQL WOrkbench I can see that whenever I persist or merge I get duplicate rows in my database tables.

I use these two methods for persist and merge:

```
public void persist(Object entity) {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();    
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(entity);
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

public void merge(Object entity) {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();     
        session.merge(entity);
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();      
    }
```

I got my user class which has a ManyToMany with note class.

```
@ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST }  )
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_note",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "empId")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "note_id")})
private Set<Note> bookmarks = new HashSet<>();
```

note:

```
@Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long projectId;
```

and a third class which has a OneToMany relation with note.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "organisation_note", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "OrganisationId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "note_id") })
    private Set<Note> bookmarks = new HashSet<>();
```

I've been looking around, and can't seem to find any topics on duplicated rows in the database. The first persist won't duplicate the row, but the second will, and the third will throw the exception. After that it's just exceptions after each time I try to persist. Which is not that reliable. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: at your sql structure, you have an auto increment id?

Comment: yes for both JoinTable I use Id, with auto increment.

Comment: how do you invoke the persist method?

Comment: DAO.persist(entity);   I call it from my servlet. DAO is ofc an instance of the class that has the persist method.